# How to convert ImageSourse to NSUrl or CGImage in xamarin ios

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, nsurl

I want to convert the ImageSource or image byte array to Xamarin.ios NSUrl or CGImage. How  to implement this. I am generating the byte Array from LayoutView like below. So after getting the the byte array I need to convert it to NSUrl or CGImage for printing that layout. From the below code I will get the bytearray.

```
public byte[] LayoutToImage()
{
    var view = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
    UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(view.Frame.Size);
    view.DrawViewHierarchy(view.Frame, true);
    var image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
    using (var imageData = image.AsPNG())
    {
        var bytes = new byte[imageData.Length];
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

I am able to print the image on the iOS project resource file, like that I need to print the layout view also.

```
 string fileName = "SampleImg.png";
 string localDocUrl = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, fileName);var Error = Driver.PrintImageWithURL(new NSUrl(localDocUrl), pSettings);
```

Comment: `GetImageFromCurrentImageContext` returns a `UIImage` which can be converted to a `CGImage`.  I don't know why you need all the extra steps to create a `byte[]`?  Your question is not very clear

Comment: @Jason Actually I want to create NSUrl path from the above byte array or UIImage for printing that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jason said `GetImageFromCurrentImageContext` returns a UIImage. If you want to convert to CGImage, you can directly use `UIImage.CGImage` to get CGImage. Converting a byte array to a CGImage also needs to be converted to a UIImage first.